# Crystal report having number of subreports are overridding the data of another subreport

Tags: database, crystal-reports, overriding

I have created a crystal report with number of subreports and I tried to put these subreports in different different detail section and in report footer too but for both the cases it is over riding the data of other crystal reports. Could you please let me know how can i generate the whole data in a proper format without over riding any data.

Comment: Please be more specific. Are subreports overlappin each other although you have put them in different Detail sections? Can you show us a screenshot of your Design and of your Preview result?

Comment: Verify if you checked "underlay following sections" in the "section expert" of the detail section. It should NOT be checked.